# Can't check permissions in fragment using Sdk 23?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I'm trying to check a permission in a fragment and the 'checkSelfPermission' cannot be resolved. What is going on here?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: if it is `Marshmallow`, no need to use `ActivityCompat` you can directly call `requestPermissions`

Comment: Yeah it's Marshmallow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
```

Comment: Now it's saying ``permission.CAMERA`` can't be applied. Maybe prefacing it with getActivity()?

Comment: I'll accept the answer in 8 minutes lol. I hate that it makes you wait.

Comment: if granted by user than how to call fragment method. my camera is not opening after doing same as u told.

Comment: This should be just a check before your call to the camera. If the permission is granted it shouldn't stop you to call the camera.